# SQL использует не всю память системы

Tags: sql-server

Здравствуйте!

Система:

- Intel(R)Xeon(R)CPU X5560 @ 2.80 Ghz, 12GB of RAM

ПО:

- MS Windows Server 2003 R2 Enterprise
- x64 Edition MSSQL2005ENT.x64

SQL использует не всю память системы, в Диспетчере задач видно как SQL использует только 200МБ физической памяти и около 400МБ виртуальной памяти. База весит 167 Гб.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать так, чтобы SQL использовал всю свободную память, тем самым повысить производительность системы в целом.

Comment: Предположу что это где то в настройках. Ковыряйте админскую оснастку для MSSQL.

Answer (score 1):

Может быть я ошибаюсь, но насколько мне известно, Диспетчер Задач **не показывает** shared memory, которую задача запросила и пользуется ей м.б. совместно с другими.

А вот как посмотреть какие сегменты shared memory доступны задаче и вообще каков их размер, я не знаю.

Думаю, что дело в этом.

Answer (score 0):

На вашем экземпляре SQl Server только одна бд висит или есть еще? В момент снятия данных по используемой памяти запросы шли к бд? Возможно стоит проверить настройки Resource Governor.